# Ubuntu 21.10 Flickering Screen on Wake or Screen Resolution Change

Tags: screen, flicker, 21.10

When I wake my computer, the login screen and DE looks like the graphics card is broken (it's not). the screen has flickering lines and blocks of the screen flickering off an on. The manual resolution to this is to change the toggle my refresh rate from 165 to 60 Hz. The flickering doesn't occur until I change my screen resolution or log out.

This occurs on Wayland and X11. See the below image.

[Video of flickering screen](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ekwXaG65ijJUXNsrgQcjIpqiW74uAAf5/view?usp=sharing)

I have searched and haven't found anything that represents what I'm experiencing.

My setup:

- Laptop: Lenovo Legion 5 Pro
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7
- GPU: NVIDIA RTX 3070, driver version 470
- Graphics: hybrid mode, AMD Renoir
- Refresh Rate: 165Hz
- Ubuntu: 21.10
- DE: Gnome 40.4.0
- Linux Kernel: 5.13.0-20-generic